# Windows 8.1: file content searching, indexed location, unkown/no file type

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, search

I have (text) files without extension located in an indexed location. Is it possible using Windows 8.1 to search in their content?

Problems:
1. They have no extension, so I cannot specify their indexing behaviour. (Also, I rather not do that for every single file type I might want to search...)
2. Because they are located in an indexed location the Explorer option "When searching non indexed locations: Always search file names and contents" has no effect.

Any ideas? Do I really have to install a 3rd party tool just to search through file contents?

Comment: Have you seen/heard of [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/)?

Comment: @RowlandShaw No I had not. Thank you. I think it is ridiculous that I have to clutter my PC with yet another tool to do something that Windows used to be able to do without problems... *grrr*

Comment: In fairness, it's a lot better than any built in tool with previous versions of Windows...

Answer (score 1):

I'm convinced there is no way to accomplish what you want with Windows 8.1 search, however you don't need to install a 3rd party tool either. Consider two files:

```
foo.txt
foo
```

Both files contain the text "some text". If you use the windows search bar, you could search for that phrase using: **contents:"some text"** but that will only find foo.txt because extensionless files are not searched. But you can still use the built in command line tool **findstr**, like so:

```
findstr /c:"some text" *
```

or

```
findstr /s /i /c:"some text" *
```

which will include **S**ubdirectories and **I**gnore case sensitivity of the search.